# Locate and transfer NOD32 Virus updates to next computer

Tags: windows, anti-virus, nod32

I have two PCs. I have installed NOD32 in both of them. In order to update the virus defination i need to update both of them.

Can i just update in one and transfer or use the same defination/update in next computer?

if yes how can i?

Comment: Why can't you just update the definitions normally on the second machine?

Comment: Perhaps he's on a low bandwith connection, is limited to the ammount he can use and wishes to save downloading things twice.

Comment: i guess you got me joe... so what can be solution for my problem

Comment: In my experience, copying the install folder (usually Program Files\NOD32) and overwriting the existing one on the second machine (with the services stopped) has worked, but then running the update again is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

You need NOD32 Update Generator. It will collect updates into specific file and you will be able to update another machine. Make sure that you using correct version of Update Generator that is compatible with your version of NOD32